# About ionic framework and geting data from server

Tags: android, mysql, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

H i'm actually working on an android app ( Ionic framework ).
I need to get data from my MySQL database.
Now i use this method :
from my app i use the $http.get(url) and the return value is data (JSON).
My problem is : if someone extract the APK file he can use the API in his own app, or he can fetch all data from database.
Is there an other method to get data from MYSQL database ?
How i can secure my app ?

Answer (score 1):

You should make some kind of authentication mechanism, for example, a token in the header, that way you know wether the user has access to that resource or not.

So when you make your request you can generate a configuration for that particular request.

Example:

```
var url = "http://yourserver.com/api/your/path";
var config = {
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer someBearerFromTheServer"
    }
};
$http.get(url, config);
```

The backend implementation for this to work depends on the language you use. Here google is your best friend.

A more advanced way to do this, is to use `interceptors` in the `$http` service and attach the token to the header in every request, but be careful, you should secure this so you won't send your credentials to every request you make (sometimes your app might need to request data from another server).

You can read more about `$http` services and its configurations in the [$http service documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 0):

You should make [API](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm), and use for example [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), to retrieve data from database.

---

**[Loading JSON data into an Ionic app using Angular JS’ $http service](http://samcroft.co.uk/2016/loading-json-into-an-ionic-app/)**

> This article is split into two parts:
>
> - Explanation and code examples for loading data using Angular JS’    $http service.
> - How this can be applied to load data into an Ionic app, with a full    example.

Comment: I have already implement the code that get JSON data into an Ionic app using Angular JS’ $http service.
I send request to php file in my server and i get result in JSON.
but the problem is when someone extract (unzip ) application file he could find the php file url so he can make http request  and this is the problem

Comment: In that case you should put API for example on shared hosting and access  it `$http.get` through URL `http://www.example.com/API/script.php`. Also, you can use Postman in Google Chrome for testing API.

Comment: the problem is if some one know the url http://www.example.com/API/script.php 
he can use this in his app
and he can get it easily by unzipping apk file

Comment: This can be easily achieved using the node js https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens, but if you want to use PHP for backend then something like this `http://www.example.com/API/script.php?username=abc&pswd=xyz`